# interrupt thread with start_consuming method of pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a thread which listens for new messages from rabbitmq using pika. After configuring the connection using BlockingConnection, I start consuming messages throught start_consuming. How can I interrupt the start consuming method call to, for example, stop the thread in a gracefully manner?

Comment: send a basic_cancel from your consumer? Make your consumer listen from a control queue that injects a "quit" message whenever the consumer needs to stop?

Comment: `channel.stop_consuming()`. Call it in the callback registered with `basic_consume` when you receive a "quit" message. Put your graceful stop instructions after `channel.start_consuming()`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [consume generator](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.html#BlockingChannel.consume) instead of start_consuming.

```
import threading

import pika


class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__()
        self._is_interrupted = False

    def stop(self):
        self._is_interrupted = True

    def run(self):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters())
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare("queue")
        for message in channel.consume("queue", inactivity_timeout=1):
            if self._is_interrupted:
                break
            if not all(message):
                continue
            method, properties, body = message
            print(body)

def main():
    thread = WorkerThread()
    thread.start()
    # some main thread activity .....
    thread.stop()
    thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The `inactivity_timeout=1` argument and `continue` statement is genius! You made my day, thank you.

Comment: This is a busy-wait loop but with pika connections not being thread safe this is the best possible answer.

Comment: This is really helpful, can't believe I didn't see this in the docs previously.. going to use pika this way from now on...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, to make it work for me, I had to change `if not message` to `if not all(message)` since the message is a `tuple` `(None, None, None)`